# LB1847 stepper controller :how to connect to grbl atmega based board with step ,direction,enable , limit?

Tags: stepper

I like to use an LB1847 chip with stepper motor "both salvaged from old copier". I made a GRBL AtMega board, this board gives step, direction, enable and limit leads.

So I tried to find the corresponding pins on the LB1847, but the data sheet only shows enable1 and enable2 pins and phase1 and phase2 pins?

So how can I connect the step and direction and enable pins of AtMega to these pins of LB1847?

There are other logic pins on LB1847 chip to control current and decay.
If the data sheet is required i can upload it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide a link to the datasheet

Comment: Link to datasheet: https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LB1847-D.PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that most people use an Arduino CNC Shield to connect their Arduino Uno (running GRBL software) to the drivers of the stepper-motors. Via Google you find plenty of them, for example: [here](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1750) and [here](https://www.hobbyelectronica.nl/product/arduino-cnc-shield/). The schematics of the latter example are published [here](https://github.com/synthetos/grblShield/tree/master/hardware/gshield_v5_schematic). You could use the information from this schematic to make your own 'interface' between the Arduino and the LB1847 driver chips.